# trouble creating directory backups of selected directories

Tags: command-line, bash, backup, tar

I have to a create directory backups of selected directories; each backup should have only one root directory; if multiple directories are selected, then each of them should be stored in a separate backup. Backups should use tar and gzip. I wrote a script that should somewhat achieve this but I keep getting an error that cannot stat:

```
no such file name or directory
```

Code:

```
DATE=$(date +"%d-%b-%Y")
cd ~/comp232/lab5
tar zcvf lab5-$DATE.tgz lab5
mv *.tgz ~/Documents
```

I have Been looking up the problem online but the solutions I've tried such removing the hyphen between tar and zcvf does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the script correctly, and not mis-typing the filename or something? Try running the script with a `./` in front of the script name, for example `./script.sh`

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your Script but this long time not already does what you want to achieve:

```
DATE=$(date +"%d-%b-%Y")
cd ~/comp232/
tar -caf lab5-$DATE.tgz lab5
mv *.tgz ~/Documents
```

However assuming all directories you want to `.tgz`are in the same parent folder you can do something like this:

```
DATE=$(date +"%d-%b-%Y")
cd ~/comp232/
for f in ./* # for each entry in directory do
do
    if [ -d "$f" ] # making sure $f is a directory
    then
        tar -caf "$f-$DATE".tgz $f
    fi
done
mv *.tgz ~/Documents
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Oh i just saw my script proposal will aswell put single files in the parent directory into a tgz file let me edit my answer then you can accept it. There you go.